# Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm looking at the tutorial on hyperledger fabric (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html).

The tutorial mentions command `peer chaincode invoke`, which accepts

```
--ctor string                    Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
```

What's the specification of the JSON message? Is there a documentation available?

I know what JSON is, but what is the format required by **the** JSON?

The tutorial shows two usages, e.g.  `-c '{"function":"TransferAsset","Args":["asset6","gqq"]}'` and `-c '{"Args":["GetAllAssets"]}'`

Besides "function" and "Args", can I do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

non-empty JSON chaincode parameters must contain the following keys: 'Args' or 'Function' and 'Args'

this are source code

```
if chaincodeCtorJSON != "{}" {
        var f interface{}
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(chaincodeCtorJSON), &f)
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrap(err, "chaincode argument error")
        }
        m := f.(map[string]interface{})
        sm := make(map[string]interface{})
        for k := range m {
            sm[strings.ToLower(k)] = m[k]
        }
        _, argsPresent := sm["args"]
        _, funcPresent := sm["function"]
        if !argsPresent || (len(m) == 2 && !funcPresent) || len(m) > 2 {
            return errors.New("non-empty JSON chaincode parameters must contain the following keys: 'Args' or 'Function' and 'Args'")
        }
    } else {
        if cmd == nil || (cmd != chaincodeInstallCmd && cmd != chaincodePackageCmd) {
            return errors.New("empty JSON chaincode parameters must contain the following keys: 'Args' or 'Function' and 'Args'")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then once I fill in the required key, what are the specifications of the value?

Comment: The value of `function`should be your chaincode function name,the value of `Args` should be your chaincode function params

Comment: What are the specifications of 'Args' only? Since you are saying  ('Args') or ('Function' and 'Args').

Comment: I also interpret your answer as that Hyperledger Fabric does not have documentation on the details in that you are unable to give a link.

Comment: if you input Args only ,then your first param shoud be your chaincode function name,for instance, your chaincode parameters can contain `Args` only,the json format should be `'{"Args":["TransferAsset","asset6","gqq"]}'`,your chaincode parameters can contain `Args` and `Function`,then the the json format should be `'{"Function":"TransferAsset","Args":["asset6","gqq"]}'`

Comment: yes,there is no official document,but I have experiment many times,I think it should be ok

Comment: In addition，use `Args` or `Args` and `Function` are depending on how to get args on your chaincodes,generally speaking,my chaincode use `stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()`,this function returns the first argument as the function name and the rest of the arguments as parameters in a string array.